# Find a Nonsingular matrix in Jordan Form

Tags: matrices

Let $$ A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
\end {pmatrix}
$$

Find a nonsingular matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is in Jordan form.

The course I am taking uses the textbook "Matrices and Linear Transformation" by Cullen.

The example in the book explains how to find $P$ if I know the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

When I tried to find the characteristic polynomial of this matrix, I got TWO eigenvalues: 0 and 1.

According to the example, I need to first find the matrix J which A is similar to.

[Theorem 5.12](http://books.google.com/books?id=fqUTMxPsjt0C&pg=PA197) in my textbook states:If $A \in F_{n\times n}$ has characteristic polynomial $c(x)=\det(xI-A)=\prod^{r}_{i=1}(x-\lambda_{i})^{s_{i}}$ then $A$ is similar to a matrix $J$ with the $\lambda_{i}$ on the diagonal, zeros and ones on the subdiagonal, and zeros elsewhere.

Am I correct in saying
$$J=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. The Jordan blocks in your case are $$J_2(0) = \pmatrix{0 & 0\\ 1 & 0} \\ J_1(1) = \pmatrix{1}.$$
You need to look at Theorem 5.13 in your book.

Comment: J.D I am trying to follow an example in the book which uses the similar Jordan matrix to then determine the matrix P.  However, the example works with a matrix A where there was only one eigenvalue.  The example is on page 204, can you tell me how I would have to modify this so that it works for this matrix?

Comment: can you help me find P? the example in the book works with a matrix which has one eigenvalue.  The example is on pg204.

Comment: @sarah: Google Books doesn't show me p. 204 in the book.

Comment: I guess this is now covered by copper.hat's answer on your other question: [click here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171235/find-a-nonsingular-matrix-p-given-that-a-is-similar-to-a-jordan-matrix).